# Files missing when copying from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, scp, smb

I have a weird situation and I don’t know how to fix it: I have a Windows 10 running on a virtual machine that shares a directory. This directory gets mounted on a Linux machine using SMB. The problem is that when I try to copy a folder (with something like 700 files inside) from Linux to this SMB directory, some of the files are not copied. Here is the thing though, I tried `cp`, `scp`, `rsync` and even `unzip` to the target, and I still can’t get all files inside. Moreover, the number of files that are missing is not always the same — I get between 670 and 700 files, but in an unreliable way. Also, this “error” is silent, so I don’t even know when and why some files are not copied.

I don’t even know how to debug this thing, nonetheless how to fix it, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having had similar issues between Windows and Linux on separate machines, I found that sometimes a "pull" from a shared folder on one machine to another works better, and sometimes a "push", i.e., pasting from one to another works better. It appears to be some sort of SMB timeout problem.

Comment: Is the virtual machine VirtualBox?  Can you use the guest services to share between the two instead?  BTW, I too have done the same scenario as @DrMoishe_Pippik (seperate machines) and ***never*** dropped files.  I am guessing that he is right about the SMB timing problem.  The pain is when the windows side drops while smb mount is active.

Comment: There is not enough information to advise here.  This could be a file permission problem, and/or limitations of differences in file name restrictions and/or spaces or special characters and limitations of the copying commands.   I might be inclined to do a copy, then discern the missing files (maybe using ls + sort + uniq -c or diff), then look at what is special about the files that did not copy.

Comment: I was able to isolate the issue, so I’ve added the solution in case somebody might need it in the future. Thanks @DrMoishePippik for the timeout suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be some sort of timeout problem at the beginning of the copy process. After several tests, I was able to isolate the problem and reproduce it. Between the creation of the directory on the target and the copy of the files inside it, there was a timeout and thus the first files (random number) were not copied. Why? I have no idea.

The original flow was as follows:

```
/source/directory/files.zip --> /target/directory/files/file_1
                                                 /files/file_2
                                                 :
                                                 :
                                                 /files/file_x
```

So, doing

```
unzip /source/directory/files.zip -d /target/directory
```

should have resulted in

```
/target/directory/files/file_1 to file_x
```

Doing unzip like above or doing unzip inside a different local directory and then `cp` or `mv` like this

```
unzip /source/directory/files.zip
cp -r /source/directory/files /target/directory
```

or

```
unzip /source/directory/files.zip
mv /source/directory/files /target/directory
```

didn’t work as well.

What I ended up doing was a two-step script like below, putting a delay in-between the two steps.

```
unzip /source/directory/files.zip
mkdir /target/directory/files
sleeep 2
mv /source/directory/files/* /target/directory/files
```